# Shut the default web page of Apache Aries down

Tags: jax-rs, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, aries

I am using the Apache Aries in karaf. I have setup my homepage in a separate bundle. The problem is that when i stop the 'web-home' bundle of mine, I see the apache aries default page.

In the karaf-logs I see the default page is always called anyway.

```
"WARN JAXRSUtils  - Both org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.internal.DefaultWeb#home and my.packet.Home#home are equal candidates for handling the current request which can lead to unpredictable results"
```

This is how my `Home.java` looks like:

```
@Path("/")
@Component(
    property = {
        JaxrsWhiteboardConstants.JAX_RS_APPLICATION_SELECT + "=(osgi.jaxrs.name=.default)",
        JaxrsWhiteboardConstants.JAX_RS_RESOURCE + "=true"
    },
    service = Home.class
)
public class Home {...
```

So, how does one configure the Aries to shut its homepage off, or otherwise just prevent this potentially unpredictable result?

I'd be happy to clarify further necessary details if asked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like the DefaultWeb is created by a configuration called **default.web** at the [WhiteBoard class](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/14d481f5442f54515093e2d702cd5ca0d2d1a7b4/jax-rs.whiteboard/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jax/rs/whiteboard/internal/Whiteboard.java) right here:

```
return OSGi.register(
            Application.class,
            () -> new DefaultApplication() {

                @Override
                public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
                    Object defaultApplication = _configurationMap.get(
                        "default.web");

                    if (defaultApplication == null ||
                        Boolean.parseBoolean(defaultApplication.toString())) {

                        return Collections.singleton(new DefaultWeb());
                    }
                    else {
                        return Collections.emptySet();
                    }
                }

            },
```

Looking at the [bundle activator](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/284ecf55c706299d4f7787cb71c28776bc2615ec/jax-rs.whiteboard/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jax/rs/whiteboard/activator/CxfJaxrsBundleActivator.java) it looks like that if you set the configuration **default.web** to false it will disable the Default page.

In order to do that, create or find this file:

```
.../etc/org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.default.cfg
```

(Which is the default config file of this bundle. As a general rule, the default config file is: `../etc/<Persistent ID of Bundel.cfg)`
and add / set this line:

```
default.web=false
```

Comment: It looks like it uses the ConfigAdmin to set the property, so if you create a file named  org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.cfg at the karaf /etc folder it should wire to the bundle and get the property from there.

Comment: Or org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.default.cfg, since the PID is org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.default for the Aries JaxRS Whiteboard bundle.